# Using python unittest, how can I assert an error reported gave a certain message?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Let's say I have a method that looks like this:

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1:
        raise RuntimeError('error message A')
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('error message B')
```

Using python's builtin unittets library, is there any way to tell WHICH `RuntimeError` was raised? I have been doing:

```
import unittest
from myfile import my_function


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, my_function, arg1, arg2)
```

But this only asserts that a `RuntimeError` was encountered. I want to be able to tell WHICH `RuntimeError` was encountered. Checking the actual error message is the only way I think this could be accomplished but I can't seem to find any assert method that also tries to assert the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## unittest users:

In this case, it is better to use [assertRaisesRegex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex).

> Like `assertRaises()` but also tests that regex matches on the string representation of the raised exception. regex may be a regular expression object or a string containing a regular expression suitable for use by `re.search()`.

So, you could use:

```
self.assertRaisesRegex(RuntimeError, "^error message A$", my_function, arg1, arg2)
```

## pytest users:

Install my plugin [pytest-raisin](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-raisin).  Then you can assert using matching exception *instances*:

```
with pytest.raises(RuntimeError("error message A")):
    my_function(arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `assertRaises` as a context manager and assert that string value of the exception object is as expected:

```
def my_function():
    raise RuntimeError('hello')

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError) as cm:
            my_function()
        self.assertEqual(str(cm.exception), 'hello')
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/7J0HOR

Comment: –1 Your code will not work, since the assertion on the exception string is unreachable

Comment: Indeed. Fixed then.

Comment: The edited code works. I accepted the other answer though since assertRaisesRegex syntax is much nicer

Comment: @Rosey Indeed, although keep in mind that the `assertRaisesRegex` method is only available in Python 3, so if your project ever needs to support Python 2 you would have to settle with this more verbose approach.

Comment: @blhsing incorrect, it's available in Python 2 but it's called `assertRaisesRegexp`.

Comment: @wim Ah thanks I stand corrected. Not sure how I never noticed this method when I read through the documentation of `unittest` back then.